# Are there any useful generalizations of homomorphisms that can apply to a graded valuation ring?

Tags: abstract-algebra, valuation-theory, ring-homomorphism, graded-rings, graded-modules

I have two graded valuation rings, $R$ and $S$, that I want to relate by a function $f:R\rightarrow S$.  The problem is that $f$ is only a group homomorphism under addition for two elements of $R$ that have the same valuation.  In any case, however, if $v_R(u) < v_R(v)$ then $v_R(f(u+v)) = \min\{v_R(u), v_R(v)\}$.

What can I do from here?

Comment: Is $f$ supposed to be well-behaved with respect to the multiplicative structure in any way? Also, do you have some non-trivial examples for such maps at hand?

Comment: Actually, do you mean that $f(u+v)=f(u)+f(v)$ for all $u, v$ with $v_R(u)=v_R(v)$? Because I think from that it quickly follows that $f$ is additive on the entire ring. Or do you just mean it for all $u,v$ with $v_R(u)=v_R(v) =v_R(u+v)$?